# Haskell newtype definition

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I don't understand this newtype definition ad the following code ;

```
newtype Prod a =  Prod { getProd :: a }  

instance Num a => Monoid (Prod a) where  
    mempty = Prod 1  
    Prod x `mappend` Prod y = Prod (x * y)
```

Then I run the following query:

```
Ghci > getProd $ Prod 2 `mappend` Prod 5  
    -> 10
```

How im getting this result and how is getProd involved with this result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How am I getting this result?

Lets look at how this is evaluated:

```
Prod 2 `mappend` Prod 5
```

Yields

```
Prod 10
```

The back ticks are just sugar for `mappend (Prod 2) (Prod 5)`

This makes sense because of the definition for `mappend`:

```
Prod x `mappend` Prod y = Prod (x * y)
```

It pattern matches against `Prod` for each argument, and binds their numbers to `x`, and `y` respectively. Those two are then multiplied and used to construct a new `Prod` with their product as the value.

Finally, in order to get the result out of the product you have to use `getProd`, which just unwraps the value inside of a `Prod`.

Answer (score 1):

`Prod` itself doesn't do much; it's just a wrapper around an arbitrary type. Its purpose, though, is to serve as a basis for the given `Monoid` instance, which is for multiplication.

`` Prod x `mappend` Prod y `` resolves to `x * y`, for whatever definition of `*` is provided by the `Num` instance for `x` and `y`. The call to `getProd` simply extracts the wrapped value from the result.